# VBA Subtract two dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have this problem, I want to subtract two dates from myself, but I still have Run Time Error 13, Type mismarch
The task is to subtract the date from the cell (cell format: Date) today. I can create a cell with today's date but I would prefer not to.

````
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim ark5 As Worksheet
Set ark5 = Worksheets("Zalegle")
Dim LastRow5 As Long
Dim a As Date


LastRow5 = ark5.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
a = DateDiff("d", Now, ark5.Cells(2, "G"))

For i = LastRow5 To 2 Step (-1)
    If Date - a < 7 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        i = i - 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub```
````

Comment: Side note: get rid of that `i = i - 1` inside the loop.

Comment: Most likely you have *text-that-looks-like-a-date*.

Answer (score 0):

Using `CDate` might solve your issue, give this a try :

````
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim ark5 As Worksheet
Set ark5 = Worksheets("Zalegle")
Dim LastRow5 As Long
Dim a As Date


LastRow5 = ark5.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
a = DateDiff("d", Now, CDate(ark5.Cells(2, "G").value))

For i = LastRow5 To 2 Step (-1)
    If Date - a < 7 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub```
````

Comment: ... and drop the `i = i - 1`.

Comment: @BigBen i = i -1 is good there ?? I don't understand he substract 1 to `i` after deleting a row to not skip line

Comment: No... OP is looping from the bottom up, so `i = i - 1` *is* actually skipping a row.

Comment: Just let `For i` control what the value of `i` is. Don't modify `i` within the loop.

Comment: I add this i-1 becuse when I delet a row this row is check one more and without it even all sheet can be clear.

Comment: @gajus21 Anyway, Did ``CDate` Solve your issue ?